# POST data is empty for Google Checkout API Callback

Tags: php, api, google-checkout

I have set up the following script to test notifications of orders paid via Google Checkout:

```
<?php
    mail('max@edison.com', 'google checkout order alert', json_encode($_POST));
?>
```

I'm getting the email, but the value of the `$_POST` array is blank (in other words, the body of the email is simply `[]`).

Am I wrong to think that the values should be getting sent immediately via POST? Or is the notification request really just an opportunity for me to then request from Google the most recent order details? I.e., my above script would need to make a request to Google for the order details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Google Checkout postback request is a raw JSON post, not a typical HTTP post (which is what would be needed in order to populate the `$_POST` array). In order to read the contents of the postback request, you must get the raw post body, and `json_decode` it.

This should do the trick: `json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'))`

Comment: Thanks! It's actually a "an XML document that constitutes the body of an HTTP POST request. When receiving notification XML messages, you can obtain the value of the XML string by accessing the raw POST data". In other words, I simply didn't want the `json_decode()` function call.

Comment: Aw, sorry. I saw this URL: https://developers.google.com/in-app-payments/docs/postback#jwt but that's for Android. My bad.